# Como bloquear arquivos por extensão no SVN

Tags: svn, commit

Preciso criar um hook no SVN, de pré commit que bloqueie quaisquer arquivos que sejam com extensão ".rar" e ".zip".

E que apresente uma mensagem como " O commit foi bloqueado, esse tipo de arquivo não pode ser adicionado." (exemplo)

Comment: Por que não usar o svn ignore ao invês disso?